# why float 32 and float64 printed as integer in go?

Tags: go

I was looking at "A Tour of Go" and saw that

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    var x, y int = 3, 4
    var f float64 = math.Sqrt(float64(x*x + y*y))
    var z uint = uint(f)
    fmt.Println(x, y, z, f)
}
```

when I run this code it prints **3 4 5 5** shouldn't it be **3 4 5 5.0** I am totally new to go looked up documentation but i couldn't find any answer for this

Comment: "shouldn't it be ..."  There's no definitive reason why or why not, it is just an arbitrary choice of the `fmt` library what the default formatting should be for a floating point number.  Often the only reason why we think of a float 5 as `5.0` in other languages is because you need to write it that way to avoid type errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```golang
math.Sqrt -> float64
```

however you are using `fmt.Println`.
Try

```golang
fmt.Printf("%.1f", f)
```

`"Println formats using the default formats for its operands and writes to standard output."` https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println